# Custom TextView with alpha background in CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'd like to create something like this.
But i don't know how to make textview with alpha background.
I try to put 1 relative layout to CollapsingToolbarLayout. But it doesn't work when I collapse it.

Here is my current layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.iantsu.projectm.ui.activity.RecipeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/panelImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="24dp"
                        android:text="Title here"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:title=""
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_recipe" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: check this https://github.com/anton46/WhatsApp-ProfileCollapsingToolbar and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991395/add-gradient-to-imageview

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211936/how-to-set-background-of-collapsing-toolbar-with-custom-behavior-to-fit-whole-sc