# Add Gradient Layer to UIImageView in IOS thru CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uilabel, gradient

I am trying to add a Gradient in IOS like I did in [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991395/add-gradient-to-imageview). So I can see my label on top of the UIImageView and its not hidden.

[image]

In android I did this in a drawable  `

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#00ffffff"
    android:startColor="#aa000000"
    android:centerColor="#00ffffff" />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />
```

`

I am trying to do this in IOS Swift 4.2 and I get the following :

```
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: showImageView.frame.size.width, height: showImageView.frame.size.height)
    showImageView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

[image]

How do I get the Gradient to start black from the bottom and go up in 90 degrees?How do I change the opacity?Any idea?

Comment: Sorry its just the example so I can see the difference.Just need an easy way so I can have the label visible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. Choose colors with `alpha` less than 1. Perhaps:

   ```
   gradient.colors = [
       UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor,
       UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor
   ]
   ```
2. To have this gradient go vertically, choose start and end points that have the same `x` value. E.g. to cover bottom half, perhaps:

   ```
   gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
   gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
   ```
3. Be very careful about using `frame`. You want the layer to reference the `bounds` of the image view (using the image view’s coordinate system), not the `frame` (which specifies where the image view is in its superview’s coordinate system). If your image view happens to be at `0, 0`, you might not see a difference, but if you move the image view around at all, these will start to deviate. So, assuming you’re adding this gradient to the image view, itself, you’d use the image view’s bounds:

   ```
   gradient.frame = showImageView.bounds
   ```
4. Be aware that the `frame`/`bounds` of the image view can sometimes change. So, we will implement `layoutSubviews` in our `UIImageView` or `UITableViewCell` subclass, and update the gradient’s `frame` there, e.g.

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       gradient.frame = bounds
   }
   ```

   That way it will update the gradient’s `frame` when the view’s layout changes.

   The other solution is to define a `UIView` subclass, say `GradientView`, that renders the `CAGradientLayer` and define the base `layerClass` of that view to be a `CAGradientLayer`. Then add this view in between the image view and the label, define its constraints, and then you’ll have a gradient that changes dynamically as the `GradientView` size changes. (This `layerClass` approach has the advantage that it yields better animation/transitions than you’d get by just updating the `frame` programmatically.)

   Thus, something like:

   ```
   class GradientView: UIView {
       override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
       var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }

       var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8) {
           didSet { updateColors() }
       }

       var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0) {
           didSet { updateColors() }
       }

       override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
           configure()
       }

       required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: coder)
           configure()
       }
   }

   private extension GradientView {
       func configure() {
           updateColors()
           gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
           gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
       }

       func updateColors() {
           gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor, secondColor].map { $0.cgColor }
       }
   }
   ```
5. If you really want your white text to pop, in addition to adding gradient over the image, you might also add a black glow/shadow to the text. It’s subtle, but really makes the text pop. Just make its shadow color the same color as the gradient.

   So you can see the effect, here are four renditions of a cell, with (a) no gradient; (b) with gradient; (c) with gradient and nice gaussian blur around text; and (d) with simple shadow around text:

   [image]

   The nice, gaussian blur around the text is rendered with:

   ```
   customLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
   customLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 3
   customLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
   customLabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
   customLabel.layer.shouldRasterize = true
   ```

   I think that third rendition (with gradient over the image, with glow around the text) is best. It’s subtle, but the text really pops. But gaussian blurs are computationally expensive, so if you find this adversely affects your performance too much, you can use the fourth option, with the simple, non-blurred shadow:

   ```
   customLabel.shadowColor = .black

   // perhaps also
   // customLabel.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: -1)
   ```