# Apply gradient on VectorDrawable inside ImageView in Android programmatically

Tags: android, vector, layout, imageview, drawable

I have a vector drawable, which is inside of imageview in layout. I would like to set gradient color programmatically (depending on some cases). I'm able to set a specific color to the imageview by using ColorFilter. How can I also set a gradient to a vector drawable?

Comment: Please first clear your answer and add some explanation

Comment: What kind of explanation do you want?

I have an imageview with vector inside. I'm able to change the vector's figure color programmatically, but how can I set gradient color for it? I need to set a gradient color for the vector figure (not background).

For example, I use this to change the color of the figure.

imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED);

But it's only for a single monochromatic color. I would like to apply a gradient.

Comment: no way, just create a set of VectorDrawables

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991395/add-gradient-to-imageview ?

Comment: I don't think so. I need to change it programmatically, not in the XML.

Is there no way to change it in code? I want to make smooth gradient animation for vector drawable.